# Tetrad formalism in linearized gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

I have not seen so far any application of linearized gravity treated using the local orthonormal frame approach. Stuff, such as newtonian limit, gravitational waves, etc.

I can totally see the tetrad formalism not being particularily useful in that case, since we are already "near" the flat metric in the coordinate formalism too, but the tetrad formalism had surprised me with its usefulness many times.

I am curious if 1) it is of any pragmatic use to use tetrads instead of coordinate bases for the purpose of linearized gravity, 2) if there are any papers or textbooks around that use this approach. I am especially curious about describing gravitational waves this way.

Comment: The tetrad formalism is suited for the treatment of spinors in curved spacetime.

Comment: Oh also one of Feynman's student, Elisha Huggins, did her thesis on electrons in covariant gravity, " Quantum mechanics of the interaction of gravity with electrons: theory of a spin-two field coupled to energy". It uses perturbative tetrads.

Answer (score 2):

A linearized (perturbative) tetrad is a generic $f_{\mu\nu}$ tensor with no symmetry (both indices are "flat", they are lowered or raised with $\eta$ metric tensor). The antisymmetric part of this tensor is not coupling to matter and can be ignored. The symmetric part is actually the Pauli-Fierz spin 2 field $h_{\mu\nu}$ up to a numerical factor. Therefore, general relativity in linearized tetrads is identical to general relativity in linearized metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ which was sort of obvious. Tetrads are important into semiclassical treatments of spinorial matter, thus a linearization of this theory makes using tetrads pointless.